# PHP File Upload No Page Refresh

Tags: php, iframe, upload

I know this has been asked by a few people but I haven't seen the answer.  I have a php upload form for a file upload in a div tag.  Is it possible to submit the form and upload the file without a page refresh?  I haven't found the plugins to work because I want to submit the form with a title and other data attached as well.  Any suggestions?  I looked at using an iframe, but i'm not sure it will work in an upload.php wrapped in a div tag?

Comment: try submitting to an iframe(you can just set the style display to none)

Comment: http://ramui.com/articles/ajax-file-upload-using-iframe.html yeah hidden iframe is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the most simple solution you can use: [Image upload without page refresh](http://php-drops.blogspot.ca/2011/02/image-upload-without-page-refresh.html).

No obligation to use the javascript part, but it gives you the opportunity to show a notice that the transfer has been correctly done.

If you are open to jQuery and want a more open solution, I suggest you to take a look at the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) that can manage it all for you, with some extras that could be interesting.

Comment: Do all of these solutions require HTML?  Because the form is all in php and is called into a div id on the page by jquery.  So the jquery form plug script, where would I call that?  Sorry if that's a stupid question

Comment: Actually your form is in HTML, only the treatment of it is in PHP/Javascript. So yes, you have to. For the jQuery Form Plugin, you should have a little experience before using it. You should follow tutorials.

Comment: Ok so you can use an iframe so the page won't be reloaded.  Is it possible to have the form submit to success.php where it is checked and the results (error message or success) loaded into a <div id="success"></div> on the same page without a page refresh?

Comment: Yes it is, if you usethe jQuery plugin I suggested you to use. Read the doc, but it's definitely possible.

Answer (score 1):

My favourite tool for this is [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/).  It includes real-time progress indicators, drag-and-drop, etc.

There are other, older solutions as well, including [this one](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/10/model-file-upload-overlay-box-jquery.html).  That page has a simple demo that may provide a good example for how to do this on your own.

Honourable mention goes to [Dave Walsh's facebook-lightbox](http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-lightbox), into which you *might* be able to put a file upload form.  Worth a try if you like the look.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like AIM (http://www.webtoolkit.info/). And you should really get a little more experience on html, php and js.